# Correctly storing in data structure in Python

Tags: string, list, integer, storing-data

```
alone,1

amazed,10

amazing,10

bad,1

best,10

better,7

excellent,10
```

These are some of the keywords and their 'values' that I **need to store in a
data structure, preferably a list**. Each line will be later used to access/extract the word and its 'value'.

The list I made in a while loop was:

```
line = KeywordFile.readline()

while line != '':

   line=KeywordFile.readline()
   line = line.rstrip()
```

And I tried to convert it to a list form by doing this:

```
   list=[line]
```

However, when I print the list, I get this:

```
   ['amazed,10']
   ['amazing,10']
   ['bad,1']
   ['best,10']
   ['better,7']
   ['excellent,10']
```

I don't think that I'll be able to extract my 'values' from the lists that easy if they are **inside** quotation marks.

I'm looking for a better way to store the words and its 'value'

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A dictionnary is what you need here:
You could do something like:

```
line = KeywordFile.readline()

while line != '':

   line=KeywordFile.readline()
   line = line.rstrip().split(',')
   out[line[0]] = line[1]
```

`out` will look like

```
{ 'amazed' : 10, 'amazing': 10, 'bad':1 ...}
```

and the values can be accessed `out['amazed']` will return `10`

Comment: If my answer fixes your issue (and given https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47315857/matching-keywords-in-a-dictionary-to-a-list-in-python i guess it did) would you mind accepting my answer ? Thanks