# Matching keywords in a dictionary to a list in Python

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, matching

The following dictionary gives the word and its value:

```
keywords = {'alone': 1, 'amazed': 10, 'amazing': 10, 'bad': 1, 'best': 10, 'better': 7, 'excellent': 10, 'excited': 10, 'excite': 10}
```

Following the dictionary are **two** tweets in a list in a list.
For each tweet, we need to find which of the words from **keywords** are present in it.

```
tweets = [['work', 'needs', 'to', 'fly', 'by', '', "i'm", 'so', 'excited', 'to', 'see', 'spy', 'kids', '4', 'with', 'then', 'love', 'of', 'my', 'life', '', 'arreic'], ['today', 'is', 'going', 'to', 'be', 'the', 'greatest', 'day', 'of', 'my', 'life', 'hired', 'to', 'take', 'pictures', 'at', 'my', 'best', "friend's", 'gparents', '50th', 'anniversary', '60', 'old', 'people', 'woo']]
```

The target is to find the **sum of the keyword values** found in each tweet line.

The code created **needs to be a loop** because there are more than 2 tweets.
I do not understand how I should execute this process.

Appreciate your insight!

Comment: What have you tried? Do have any questions related to a problem you're having?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
keywords = {'alone': 1, 'amazed': 10, 'amazing': 10, 'bad': 1, 'best': 10, 'better': 7, 'excellent': 10, 'excited': 10, 'excite': 10}
tweets = [['work', 'needs', 'to', 'fly', 'by', '', "i'm", 'so', 'excited', 'to', 'see', 'spy', 'kids', '4', 'with', 'then', 'love', 'of', 'my', 'life', '', 'arreic'], ['today', 'is', 'going', 'to', 'be', 'the', 'greatest', 'day', 'of', 'my', 'life', 'hired', 'to', 'take', 'pictures', 'at', 'my', 'best', "friend's", 'gparents', '50th', 'anniversary', '60', 'old', 'people', 'woo']]
total = 0

for i in keywords:
    for j in tweets:
        if i in j:
            occourance = j.count(i)
            print('keyword=', i)
            total += keywords[i]*occourance
print('sum is: ', total)




output:  
    keyword= best
    keyword= excited
    sum is:  20
```

Comment: That would be voting collusion. Don't do that.

Comment: This answer checks for keywords in the tweets. Which is inefficient and in some cases incorrect.

Comment: Repeat some word multiple times in a tweet and it won't work. You're also shadowing a builtin which is a bad idea. You're also doing an unnecessary list lookup.

Comment: No, you aren't.

Comment: No, it isn't efficient. You only need to do a single pass over the tweets and tweet words. By using `.count`, you end up doing *multiple* passes.

Comment: So, something as simple as `sum(keyword.get(word, 0) for tweet in tweets for word in words)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga    No, we can not use it because this question is easy. It means that the person who asked this question, is a beginner for Python. So if we use it, the person will not understand the answer. we can not use advanced level coding.

Comment: Sure, but as this person is a beginner we want to be _extra_ careful that we use __correct__ code - which you are not doing.

Comment: You can always expand into a for loop. The point is, you only need a single pass over the words.

Answer (score -1):

First we need to assign a variable for the value and set this to zero, then for each tweet and for every word inside this tweet we use the function `dict.get()` to get the corresponding value of word (if the word isn't in keywords it returns 0).

```
value = 0
for tweet in tweets:
    for word in tweet:
        value += keywords.get(word,0)
```

Comment: This answer is needlessly inefficient.

Comment: @miradulo please tell me what is inefficient?

Comment: First, `if word in keywords.keys()` is an anti-pattern. Firstly, it is not necessary to call `.keys`, just `x in my_dict` is sufficient for checking membership. Even worse, on Python 2, it creates a *list of keys*, then does an O(n) lookup. On Python 3, it is merely redundant. Rather, **just use the dictionary**, i.e. `value += keywords.get(word, 0)`

Comment: Thanks! Not that much experience with dictionaries, learned something new today :)

Answer (score -1):

```
keywords = {'alone': 1, 'amazed': 10, 'amazing': 10, 'bad': 1, 'best': 10, 'better': 7, 'excellent': 10, 'excited': 10, 'excite': 10}
tweets = [['work', 'needs', 'to', 'fly', 'by', '', "i'm", 'so', 'excited', 'to', 'see', 'spy', 'kids', '4', 'with', 'then', 'love', 'of', 'my', 'life', '', 'arreic'], ['today', 'is', 'going', 'to', 'be', 'the', 'greatest', 'day', 'of', 'my', 'life', 'hired', 'to', 'take', 'pictures', 'at', 'my', 'best', "friend's", 'gparents', '50th', 'anniversary', '60', 'old', 'people', 'woo']]

values = []              # Here we will store the score of each tweat like an item

for tweet in tweets:     # We iterate over each tweet
    values.append(0)     # We add a new item to the list values, we'll change this number later.
    for word in tweet:   # We iterate over each word in the tweet
        values[-1] += keywords.get(word, 0) # Using .get() we get the value of a word if it's inside keyword, if not, we get a default value: 0, instead of an KeyError. 
print(values) # Obviously, print the values in console
```

If you don't like the `values.append(0)` you can change it to `new = 0` and the `values[-1]` to `tmp`. You will also need to add at the end of the first loop `values.append(tmp)`.
Also, remember that `x += y` can be read as `x = x + y`.

If you want to have a total score, you can:

```
# ^ Use the code above ^
total_value = sum(values) # It sum all the items of values
print(total_value)

# Or total new code.

total_score = 0
for tweet in tweets:
    for word in tweet:
        total_score += keywords.get(word, 0)
print(total_score)
```

Or if you want small codes:

```
total_value = sum([keywords.get(word,0) for tweet in tweets for word in tweet])

value = [sum([keywords.get(word, 0) for word in tweet]) for tweet in tweets]
```

Your choice.